# FtpOpenFile returns nil instead of file handle when uploading

Tags: delphi, ftp, wininet

I'm transferring a file using ftp in Delphi.

I am able to connect to the ftp account ok but when I try and upload a file the 
FtpOpenFile function returns nil instead of a handle the file to be uploaded.

```
hintfile := FtpOpenFile(hintconnect,PChar(tgtfn),GENERIC_WRITE,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,0);
```

If I log into the ftp site using an ftp client application and exactly the same credentials I can upload the file without a problem.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The error is ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR.  Trying to use InternetGetLastResponseInfo to get more info.

Comment: 500 Invalid PORT Command.', #13, #10, '500 'LPRT 6,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2 etc

Seems to be a known IIS FTP issue to do with back channel port numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the last error, documentation says it all:

> "Returns a handle if successful, or
>   NULL otherwise. To retrieve a specific
>   error message, call GetLastError."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384166(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE to your Internetopen call, see also

http://etutorials.org/Programming/Pocket+pc+network+programming/Chapter+2.+WinInet/File+Transfer+Protocol+FTP/

Comment: you mean your InternetConnect call